# Laptop does not shut down

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I have a Dell Inspiron 5559 running both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10. When I try to shut down the computer from Ubuntu by clicking the shutdown option, the screen becomes blank and remains in that state. I have too forcefully shutfown the laptop using the power button. Also, logging out or putting the computer to sleep by closing the lid generates the same problem.

Comment: Try `sudo shutdown -h now` from a terminal and see if the machine powers off that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line in `/etc/default/grub`

Type this command on your terminal

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

and then just update your grub settings by typing

```
sudo grub-update
```

You won't see the results right away because even after updating the grub configuration this is reloaded only on a new restart so the first time you shut down it will behave exactly as before.